# fetching one column using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following PDO statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(RID) FROM TEMP_ROUTE");
                                 $stmt->execute();
                                 $rid = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                 $rid = (int) $rid["MAX(RID)"];
```

Is there any way so that I don't have to do the last statement there. In other words I want it to fetch `$rid["MAX(RID)"]` when doing the fetch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php and try using PDO::FETCH_BOUND instead perhaps? This won't make it shorter though. Or try something like this, from http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELEXT MAX(RID) AS max FROM TEMP_ROUTE");
$stmt->execute();
$rid = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->MAX;
```